# Resizing JFrame without pack() makes my mind blown.Not obvious

Tags: java, swing, pack

I am a student of Computer Science. I gotta write a java program.Two buttons in window and clicking on one of them makes button font bigger +1 so button/buttons get bigger and they gotta fit  in window(whole two buttons visible) so window may get bigger BUT ONLY AS MUCH AS IT IS NECESSARY. It is pretty easy with pack() but calling pack() method is not allowed. Any clues?

Comment: Nobody here is going to do your homework for you.

Comment: I dont expect it. I spent much time trying to solve problem on my own and all I would expect is some kind of clue helping me writing program on my own.

Comment: You need to determine the viewable area, that is the area with out frame borders. You then need to determine the frame border and add that into the width/height calculation. You can determine the amount of space a button might like by calling its getPreferredSize method

Comment: Also good answer. Good karma for you for helping newbies :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is, once you've updated the font of the buttons, is to `revalidate` the container, ask the container for it's `preferredSize`.  Once you have this, you need to add in the `insets` of the window to this value, which will give you the minimum size that the window will need to be...

```
// Update button fonts...
container.revalidate(); // Force the container with the buttons to update
Dimension size = container.getPreferredSize();
Insets insets = frame.getInsets(); // Returns the frame's border requirements
size.width += insets.left + insets.right;    
size.height += insets.top + insets.bottom;
frame.setSize(size);
```

Now, you will need to make determinations about whether you want to reduce the size of the window as well as make it grow...

Comment: I figured sth out. I can calculate difference before and after change of size and then add it to Jframe size.It may be interesting that width change by 5 or 6 and height by 1 or 2 when Font size is changed by 1. It is not constant probably cause of non-fracture nature of Integer.Your solution looks more mature and professional so I gonna learn it :) Thank you for fast and accurate answer.First post here and nice surprise. I gonna help others when I will get expierienced :)